# Shading issues causing by connecting 2 separate meshes together

Tags: mesh, subdivision-surface

I'm a fairly new Blender user, and tried going at this for hours, I don't know the exact name of the problem I'm facing so no luck finding the solution thus far. **How I check my mesh issues is through x-ray view on object mode. The yellow lines through the mesh is the indicator of the problem.**

[image: x-ray view in object mode]

Made a circle and duped it and made a bridge in between and **now trying to connect them together but causing shading issues I tried to bevel the disconnecting edges together and it seems to be flipped on the normals** I think not too sure. Please help

[image: The shading issue on that edge]

[image: edge when beveled]

[image: sub-d mod in edit mode]

Comment: hello, it looks like there's a floating edge, maybe try a M > Merge by Distance, if it doesn't work share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Hi, have tried merging verts and edges it doesn't work and tried dissolving the edge but its passes the issues to the next edge. Also how do I share a file? Google drive ?

Comment: use pasteall.org/blend ... copy paste the link it will give you

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/8b33220fa8d84964afdeef81dc98df05 I didn't get a link, but can u open this ?

Comment: the only problem I see in the object you share is some inverted normals, just go in Edit mode, select all and press Shift N

Comment: Ahh yes Shift N is the solution, thanks very much moonboots. I keep facing this issue all the time and I don't want to start over. This helps very much, thanks again good Sir/Ma'am!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some inverted normals, just go in *Edit* mode, select all and press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>, or header menu > *Mesh > Normals > Recalculate Outside*.